# SpriteKit Texture Atlas Generator Error 2048 x 2048

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, texture-atlas

I'm trying to include a `2045 x 1536` background png in my atlas folder `(myApp.atlas)`

I get the following error from `TextureAtlas`:

```
sprikekit texture atlas generator error cannot fit input texture into a maximum supported dimensions of 2048 x 2048
```

Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-texture_atlas/AboutTextureAtlases/AboutTextureAtlases.html apperently at the compiled level the largest size an image can be is 2000x2000, but it should split the image automatically.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato so what's the solution?

Comment: make it lower then 2000x2000 and see if it still give you the error

Comment: @JohnRiselvato in order to fill up the screen for the ipad retina it needs to be 2048 x 1535 for landscape though

Comment: don't put it in an atlas, an image this size is practically an atlas in itself and you don't gain any benefit from forcing it into an atlas

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Ok got it

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I agree, I just have a follow-up question on this. Documentation says that all textures from a particular atlas will be drawn in a single draw pass. Does it mean that even if we could put multiple big textures in .atlas (like we can in .spriteatlas inside .xcassets), the system would still split them which would result in having multiple draw calls, one for every part?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D where'd you go?

Answer (score 1):

Go to build settings: search for **"texture atlas"** and change the Texture atlas maximum size to 4096 * 4096